# Como identificar elementos com valores repetidos em um array e criar um novo array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array associativo:

**Array Atual:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [num] => 51
        [totalparcial] => 2.50
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [num] => 51
        [totalparcial] => 3.70
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [num] => 52
        [totalparcial] => 5.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [num] => 52
        [totalparcial] => 22.00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [num] => 52
        [totalparcial] => 14.00
    )

)
```

Como posso pegar as informações do índice que possuem o mesmo valor em `[num]` , somar o `[totalparcial]` delas e criar um novo array com esses novos valores?

Nesse exemplo eu gostaria que o resultado final fosse um array assim:

**Array Desejado:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [num] => 51
        [totalparcial] => 6.20
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [num] => 52
        [totalparcial] => 41.00
    )
)
```

Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar:

```
$resultado = array();
foreach($array as $a){
    if(isset($resultado[$a['num']]))
         $resultado[$a['num']]['totalparcial'] += $a['totalparcial'];
    else
         $resultado[$a['num']] = $a;
}
```

Se precisar das chaves do array sequênciais e não iguais ao 'num', acrescenta:

```
$resultadoSequencial = array();
foreach($resultado as $r)
      $resultadoSequencial[] = $r;
```

Comment: Gerou o array exatamente como eu precisava! Valeu!